# Pagesource shows only html tags using phantomjs

Tags: php, phantomjs

I want to scrape one website using PHP, but when I go on that site and try to get the page source, I got this error:

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
```

Because of that, I try to get the page source using phantom js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.mywebsite.com/', function(){
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But using phantoms, I've got this as a result:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Did I make a mistake using phantoms? Or this website cannot be **scraped**?

Which way I can try to get the data from the page?

Comment: It seems to be duplicate, try to check you settings as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198893/phantomjs-on-linux-returns-empty-html-source

Comment: Similar problem, but I try solution from this answer and for me did not help :(

Comment: I just take you code, changed mywebsite.com to google.com, run in terminal `phantomjs load.js` and got full html. Could you provide real site name?

Comment: You can remove site name

Comment: @SergeyFedorov did u try with real website address?

Comment: Yep, see the answer

Comment: Also PhantomJS no longer maintained, use alternatives https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site have javascript redirect but script tried grab HTML before redirect finished and got the nothing. Need to wait some time — page will be builded or grab content after event `onLoadFinished` like this. Try with code below, it is should be working.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var homePage = "https://www.[real site name].com/";
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.2062'

page.open(homePage, function(status) {
    page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks you sooooo much, this is really amazing!